# Preserve whitespace in XSLT transformation in Oracle SOA Suite 11g

Tags: xml, xslt, oracle11g, oracle-soa

I'm trying to assign a single whitespace in an XSLT transformation in Oracle SOA Suite 11g, but so far I've had no luck.
My SOA application is deployed on a Weblogic server.
Here's what I've tried to do:

```
<imp1:myElement>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</imp1:myElement>
```

and

```
<imp1:myElement>
  <xsl:value-of select="string(' ')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</imp1:myElement>
```

I also tried with `disable-output-escaping="no"`. I even tried with:

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="blank"/>
<xsl:variable name="blank" select="string(' ')" />
...
<imp1:myElement>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$blank"/>
</imp1:myElement>
```

None of the above have worked. I'm aware that [a bug exists](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2262526), but the workaround described in the link (corresponding to the second solution that I've posted) doesn't work, it only changes the result from

```
<imp1:myElement/>
```

to

```
<imp1:myElement></imp1:myElement>
```

but still without the whitespace.

Does anyone know a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using `&#x00A0;` (no break space)?

Comment: Actually I solved with `&#160;`, which should be the same. You can go ahead and answer, it is the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a keyboard space, have a no-break space instead:

```
<xsl:text>&#x00A0;</xsl:text>
```

or

```
<xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: I was attempting with the whiteSpace restriction which didn't work. Your solution of &#160 worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following in xsl 1.0 and Oracle SOA 11.1.1.7

```
<xsl:text>&nbsp;</xsl:text>
```